# How to store a users picture in active directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

If I want to store users pictures in Active Directory, what format do I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this post and see if it helps

[Using the jpegPhoto attribute in AD - Part I](http://www.chineseinnorthamerica.com/technical/active%20directory/active%20directory%20images.html)